How to keep preview page active but not displayed in the progress line
In my form settings (/admin/structure/webform/manage/testing/settings/form) I have:
Form preview settings > Enable preview page > Optional
to be able to display the preview page, which I can access from the last step on the form by clicking the "preview" button.
The preview page is also contemplated on the "progress line" as an additional step, and this is what I need to avoid.
I mean, right now, if the form has 6 steps, it shows 7 on the progress line because of the preview page, if I disable the preview page, the step disappears, but the preview page is no longer available...
Any ideas? thanks!!
